# In Angular, how do you make the <option> text bold on selection?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, html-select, dropdown

For example:

My dropdown is having some options like:

- India
- America
- England

By default top most option is  "Choose your country". 
My problem is, on selection- if I choose India. Select should show "India" in bold, if I go back and select "Choose your country" . Select should show "Choose your country" as text (not bold) does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `ng-class`.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <select ng-model="selectedVal" ng-class="{'bold':selectedVal!='Choose'}">
    <option value="Choose">Choose</option> 
    <option value="Grandvalira">Grandvalira</option> 
    <option value="Vallnord">--Vallnord</option> 

 </select>
</div>
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/9315/)

Comment: that makes the whole select bold though

Comment: working for dynamic value  -- first it was not working for me , mistake i did is ng-class="{bold:Mymodel.country!='select'}" , i missed single quotation ..ng-class="{'bold':MyModel.country!='select'}" - works great , thanks bro ... everyone vote his answer

Answer (score 0):

Below I have typed the both javascript and angularjs to change the style of default value and selected value in select box

```js
$("#choice").change(function () {
    if($(this).val() == "0") $(this).addClass("empty");
    else $(this).removeClass("empty")
});

$("#choice").change();

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.selected_account_type = function () {
  var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#choice1' ) );
  if($scope.selectedservice == "0" ){
     myEl.addClass('empty');
  }
  else{
    myEl.removeClass('empty');
  }
};
});
```

```css
#choice option { color: black; }
.empty { color: gray; font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<select id="choice">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">Something</option>
    <option value="2">Something else</option>
    <option value="3">Another choice</option>
</select>

<select ng-app="myApp" id="choice1" ng-model="selectedservice" ng-change="selected_account_type(selectedservice)" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">Something</option>
    <option value="2">Something else</option>
    <option value="3">Another choice</option>
</select>
```